# Error 404 on an existing file in golang/gin

Tags: go

ANS: Don't use a RELATIVE path, it caused the error. Use the ABSOLUTE one. Using full path automatically changes c.File() path behavior from using relative path to absolute path.

UPD: The endpoint is being reached, but there is another problem. `c.File` in `referral.ValidateReferral` can't find registration.html, although the path should be correct. The file-tree, they are on the same level. See path below.

---

I have an HTML form, which submits to /referral/validate endpoint using POST method:

```
<form action="/referral/validate" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="referral">
  <input type="submit" value="Next">
</form>
```

This is the endpoint:

```
ref := r.Group("/referral")
{
    ref.GET("/validate", func(c *gin.Context) {
        // c.String(200, "Referral Input HTML")
        c.File("../../html/referral.html")
    })

    ref.POST("/validate", referral.ValidateReferral)
```

ValidateReferral:

```
func ValidateReferral(c *gin.Context) {
    referral := c.PostForm("referral")
    ok, err := CheckReferral(referral)
    if err != nil || !ok {
        c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusUnauthorized)
        return
    }

    c.File("../../../html/registration.html")
}
```

[Same path in powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTYbh.png)

This returns 404, what's the problem with it? Why can't it find the file? Path seems quite correct.

Comment: 404 could also be returned by some code invoked by `referral.ValidateReferral`. Add some debug logs at the top of `referral.ValidateReferral`'s body to confirm it is not being invoked?

Comment: @mkopriva That helped, thanks.
Although faced another problem - 'c.File("../../../html/registration.html")' is the page which 'ValidateReferral' might return if the referral is valid. It get's to the function, meaning the referral is valid.
The file tree is:
HTML (registration.html)
pkg/controllers/referral/ref-controller.go(Where the function is placed)

Excluded some other files for simplicity.

EDIT: Added more debug-logs and followed step by step, found it's not 404, but 401 being rewritten to 404 for not sure why.

Comment: @mkopriva NOT sure how formatting comments work, sorry. 'HTML' and 'pkg' folders are on the same level. Now the functions work properly, but the 'c.File(....../registration.html)' still doesn't work. I see it's being reached, pretty sure path is correct as well, but for some reason which I don't know, it fails to find the 'registration.html' file

Comment: Avoid relative paths. Relative paths are resolved based on the running program's current working directory. Note also that it is good practice if your programs don't break just because they are executed from a different directory. By default non-go files are not included in the compiled program, if you would like to include non-go files in your program then use the `embed` package, otherwise I'd recommend using absolute paths (you can use env vars to tell the program where the files live on the host machine).

Comment: And if you are 100% certain that the relative path resolves to the correct absolute path and matches the file's location, then another issue could simply be insufficient permission. Make sure the running program has the permission to read the file.

Comment: @mkopriva adjusting the path solved the problem, thanks!

Comment: @mkopriva Once again, how do I use absolute path instead of relative in golang/gin? Can't seem to find articles to help with that. I manually adjusted the path to check the issue last time, but I doubt it to be the correct way.

Comment: Specify the absolute path of the `html` directory as a configuration value. Whether you do that using environment variables, or cli arguments, or config files, etc. that's up to you. Then in your program you can do something like `filepath.Join(os.Getenv("HTML_DIR"), "/registration.html")` (assuming you opted for env vars and, before executing your program, you set the `$HTML_DIR` variable to the absolute path of the html dir).

Comment: @mkopriva I think I formulated my question a little wrong - c.File() is using relative path to it's own. How do I change that behavior? What's the way around it?

Comment: @mkopriva Found that, if I use full path it automatically uses full path instead of relative. Thanks and sorry for flooding.